# underline word in vim without changing its color

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I'd like use underlined text for some syntactic groups in vim. A simple example would the Search group:

```
:highlight Search cterm=underline
```

However, when I do that, all search matches also change their colors to white. Can I underline them all, but preserve their original colors?

Answer (score 2):

Easy. For new highlight groups, just leave off the `bg` / `fg` definitions. To override an existing group, use the special color `NONE`:

```
:highlight Search guibg=NONE guifg=NONE gui=underline
```

Comment: I use terminal. When I add `ctermbg=NONE ctermfg=NONE` nothing changes - All matches still turn white. Sorry, my code example was misleading

Comment: Which terminal? The Windows Console doesn't support any attributes (bold, italic, underline), and they get rendered as some background colors. In a proper color terminal like gnome-terminal, it works.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use ctermfg, ctermbg and cterm to affect highlighting in a colour terminal. 'cterm' stands for 'colour terminal'.

You can combine the colour terminal and gui terminal options to give consistent behaviour/highlighting across both:

```
:highlight Search guibg=NONE guifg=NONE gui=underline ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=NONE cterm=underline
```

Hope that helps